# Show UI (Activity/WindowManager) over lock screen & support in Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

My main goal is to show UI (With EditText, so IME support) Over the lock screen (No matter if there's PIN/Code or simple lock screen).

I know that WhatsApp application is doing it (Settings > Notification > Always show popup) so there's a solution for that.

The UI must be initialized from Service.

The view is a simple textview:

```
    textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("Hello There!");
    textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, 
    android.R.color.white));
    textview.setTextSize(32f);
```

I've tried several ways so far:
(In order to reproduce like whats app i'm doing everything when screen off receiver called)

- **Using WindowManager**

  WindowManager Params:

  params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
              PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
      params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
      params.screenBrightness = 0;

  ```
  Result: TextView is shown only after we unlock the device
  ```
- **Using Transparent activity**
  Activity style:

  true
      @android:color/transparent
      @null
      true
      true
      false

  Also, has android:showOnLockScreen="true" attribute

  ```
  Result: TextView is shown only after we unlock the device
  ```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in `onCreate()` of your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
}
```

Comment: FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is deprecated. what's the alternative?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277302/android-o-flag-show-when-locked-is-deprecated @SagarNayak

Comment: the link can be used for the activity but I am working inside service with a window manager. so I don't think I can use this.