# How do I check when a user logs onto their android device?

Tags: android

Is there any type of method/class I can utilize to see whether or not a person has logged onto their android device successfully? I want to be able to do this through android studios. Essentially, I want to check when the phone turns on and the user logs on

Ex. When a person types in their password correctly, I want to be able to bring them into my app automatically (example scenario, not what I am trying to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that "[A way to get unlock event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224637/a-way-to-get-unlock-event-in-android)" this solution works for you.

This solution is a implementation of broadcast receiver in android studio.

When you receive this event, open or close the app accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't this only work reliably for API levels below 26?

Comment: Yes, for 26 and higher it is not allowed. You can either use ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED or ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED if it helps or Please check this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280987/8432542

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I really appreciate it!