# Duplicated activity lifecycle when app is launched with screen turned OFF

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

#### A. Simple scenario (closed app)

Actions to reproduce behaviour:

1. Turn off the screen
2. Run application from Android Studio
   (at this point no lifecycle method has been called yet)
3. Turn on the screen

Here's the launcher activity lifecycle:

// we turn on the screen

- onCreate()
- onStart()
- onResume()

// launcher activity here suddenly decides to stop and restart

- **onPause()** // Is this a BUG?
- **onStop()**
- **onRestart()**
- onStart()
- onResume()

#### B. Lock-screen scenario

Actions to reproduce behaviour:

1. Turn off the screen (you should have a lock screen)
2. Send push to your app
3. Open the lock screen and click on push notification

#### C. Scenario when activity was already opened

Actions to reproduce behaviour:

1. Open your app (in launcher activity)
2. Turn off the screen
3. Send push
4. Open push from lock screen

Here's the launcher activity lifecycle:

// open activity like a normal person :)

- onCreate()
- onStart()
- onResume()

// turn off the screen causes onStop(), everythin OK

- onPause()
- onStop()

// send push and click it from lock screen

- onRestart() // FIRST RESTART because we stopped activity, it's OK
- onStart()
- onResume()
- **onPause()** // Is this a BUG?
- **onStop()**
- **onRestart()**
- onStart()
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onStop()

#### Finally

This lifecycle order and restarting does not seem very reasonable to me. Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: What does your Activity look like? Do you do anything in these callbacks?

Comment: @PPartisan, the activity is completely and utterly empty. Nothing besides Timber logging.

Comment: [Tangentially related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48277421/6759241)